# Why does `sudo poweroff` crash processes?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, crash

When I turn off my computer with `sudo poweroff`, or reboot it with `sudo reboot`, after the next launch programs (Firefox, LibreOffice, deadbeef) show their "restore-from-crash" functionality, which leads me to wonder why I bother issuing the "nice" command instead of yanking the power cord.  How can I instruct Linux to quit the programs gracefully?

Comment: Could be because `poweroff` tells the system to turn the power off. If you want a "nice" command try `shutdown now`.

Comment: @doneal24  My `man poweroff` includes a `--force` option which still "results in an immediate but clean shutdown by the system manager". You have to invoke `--force` twice to brute-force it. It does not say what skipping the option does, but presumably it should be even more considerate.

Comment: Which init system are you running ?

Comment: `sudo poweroff` is suspect; I looked into the hooks into systemd (in case your system useses it) along with the original sources. Its unclear exactly what the progression in system calls is according  to an strace. I would suggest calling `shutdown` instead.

Comment: The init system is `systemd`.  `shutdown now` makes no difference.  Going through the DE's interface neither.  I've had the same occuring on latest Ubuntu, on latest Mint, and on Arch a while ago, on different laptops.  Which doesn't make any sense because "close apps before shutdown" seems to be a self-evidently useful thing that should've been solved long ago. :shrug:

Comment: Since *shutdown* should SIGTERM before sending SIGKILL, would the timeout granted between these two actions be too low (with regard to the time your apps would need to terminate nicely) ?